# Does Juju really need two nodes?

Tags: ssh, juju, maas, openstack

Hi I am trying to deploy openstack with Juju and MAAS.
But the Juju bootstap is still with the Status Connecting to Environment:

```
marcel@ubuntu20:~$ juju -v status
2012-07-11 07:18:00,831 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2012-07-11 07:18:00,842 INFO **Connecting to environment**...
2012-07-11 07:18:00,961 DEBUG Connecting to environment using node5...
2012-07-11 07:18:00,962 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="node5" remote_port="2181" local_port="52179".
2012-07-11 07:18:01,468:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@658: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.3.5
2012-07-11 07:18:01,468:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@662: Client environment:host.name=ubuntu20
2012-07-11 07:18:01,468:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@669: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2012-07-11 07:18:01,468:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@670: Client environment:os.arch=3.2.0-23-generic
2012-07-11 07:18:01,468:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@671: Client environment:os.version=#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012
2012-07-11 07:18:01,469:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@679: Client environment:user.name=marcel
2012-07-11 07:18:01,469:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@687: Client environment:user.home=/home/marcel
2012-07-11 07:18:01,469:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@699: Client environment:user.dir=/home/marcel
2012-07-11 07:18:01,469:11263(0x7f8ffb223700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=localhost:52179 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f8ff90536b0 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x2444670 flags=0
2012-07-11 07:18:01,469:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1585: initiated connection to server [127.0.0.1:52179]
2012-07-11 07:18:01,470:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1603: Socket [127.0.0.1:52179] zk retcode=-4, errno=112(Host is down): failed while receiving a server response
2012-07-11 07:18:04,807:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:52179] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-11 07:18:08,143:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:52179] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-11 07:18:11,480:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:52179] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-11 07:18:14,816:11263(0x7f8ff5dad700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:52179] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
```

I waited now two days and nothing happened:

But I have only one node because I wanted to check if it is realy working before I continue and install more nodes. But I read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Juju
**Have at least two nodes added to your MAAS.** That I need at least two nodes. Do I really need two nodes?  that the Bootstap is working ? I am not in the lab so I can't install one more node so easy. But if it will work I will than I will go there...

And is there anyway to do the Bootstrap manually that I can do it instand. I am running out of time and I really need to deploy openstack I can't wait days to do the bootstap.

Answer (score 3):

JuJu does need 2 nodes to do anything useful.  You should be able to bootstrap your juju maas environment with 1 node, but that would be it.

It seems to me that the juju bootstrap node has had some issue in your case.  I do not think installing an additional node would fix your problem.

Could you collect (and post somewhere) the contents of:
 /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
 /var/log/cloud-init.log
 /var/log/juju

I suspect if you look in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log on the bootstrap node you might see something that points to your problem.